# How to change default CDT builder settings

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way I can edit the default 'C/C++ Build configuration' that is created when I import a Makefile project into Eclipse/CDT?

Currently, after I import a project, I go to project, properties, C/C++ Build section and then change the 'Workbench build behaviour' settings under the 'Behaviour' tab. Main reason is that I don't want the default behaviour to be 'make all' but rather 'make'. I would like to edit these default settings so I don't have to do this every time.